# How to store specific lines in a text file in a array (i.e 2 seperate bank accounts)

Tags: c#, arrays, streamreader, streamwriter

I am doing a ATM project for my computer science class and we are required to make an ATM that stores and reads accounts in a text file. I am stuck trying to figure out how I can get an array in the program to store 4 lines from the text file (Account number, Name, NIP and total balance) and be able to access them when the user enters the correct account number.

```
RBC001 (Account Number)
Ariel Bendahan (Name)
1337 (NIP)
50000 (Total Balance)
RBC002 (Same thing but second account)
John Baker (...)
6868 (...)
2500 (...)
```

^ This is the text document for reference.

I tried to make an array that stores all bank account  `BankAccount[] tabBankAccounts = new BankAccount[200];` (The array in question) but I just don't know how to exactly store 4 lines a code in each index of the array.

```
StreamReader myfile = new StreamReader("AccountInfo.txt");
            Int16 i = 0;
            while (myfile.EndOfStream == false)
            {
                tabBankAccounts[i].AccountNumber = myfile.ReadLine();
                tabBankAccounts[i].Name = myfile.ReadLine();
                tabBankAccounts[i].NIP = Convert.ToInt16(myfile.ReadLine());
                tabBankAccounts[i].TotalBalance = Convert.ToInt32(myfile.ReadLine());
            }
            myfile.Close();
```

^ The programming reading the text document.

This is more like a continuation of my first question so I'm sorry if my recent posts felt like spam.

Comment: Does it have to be an array? Lists would be easier to work with: List<List<string>>().

Comment: Don't let text files do the job of a database. But is this the requirement of your course? ( Dude ... ) If so: What exactly is the problem? You do seem to realize you need a model object with properties. If you have that this looks not _too_ far out. What you are missing is the creation of the model and setting it into the array.

Comment: But are you stuck to an array? That would be halfway decent if you knew exactly how many accounts are in that text file _before_ reading it in. How much say do you have in the structure of that text file? Is it allowed to be CSV (Comma Separated Value) or even JSON, maybe?

Comment: So, unfortunately, I'm pretty sure it has to be an array as my teacher wants us to use the things we learnt in class but if I'm getting desperate, I'll could try to use the list method but I would have to do more research on it since I wasn't taught that yet. It has to be in a text file as again, our teacher wants us to show what we learnt, which is one of the unfortunate perks of being a freshman and the way my teacher is. The only thing I'm truly missing right now is how I can make the program read 4 lines of the text file, and save it to one index of the array.

Comment: *Continuation* After it saves it to one index, the program now has to ask the user for the bank number (RBC001 or RBC002), display the proper name and enter the NIP. After that, the user chooses to either deposit money, withdraw money or display the account's info (total balance, NIP, bank number and name).

Comment: So you're constrained to the data store being a text file in that format, and to reading it into an array rather than a List or Dictionary? Looks like you've pretty much nailed reading it into an array (although you need an `i++` at the end of your `while` block, otherwise every account will overwrite the previous account at index 0 of your array).

Comment: Yeah, I tried adding i++ at the end of the while block, but it just ends up making the program unable to read any account numbers (RBC001 or RBC002). If I remove the i++, it only reads RBC002's account info (name, NIP, total balance).

Answer (score 0):

when you initialize an array with `BankAccount[] tabBankAccounts = new BankAccount[200];`, all the elements in the array are still null, which means first you have to create an instance for each bank account in order to set the AccountNumber etc.

Basically like this:

```
            StreamReader myfile = new StreamReader("AccountInfo.txt");
            Int16 i = 0;
            while (myfile.EndOfStream == false)
            {
                BankAccount bankAccount = new BankAccount();

                bankAccount.AccountNumber = myfile.ReadLine();
                bankAccount.Name = myfile.ReadLine();
                bankAccount.NIP = Convert.ToInt16(myfile.ReadLine());
                bankAccount.TotalBalance = Convert.ToInt32(myfile.ReadLine());

                tabBankAccounts[i] = bankAccount;
                i++;
            }
            myfile.Close();
```

also you forgot to increment `i` after each iteration, which means you would have only set the values of the first bank account

Comment: Hi, I added your correction to my code, but the i++ at the end of the while block seems to prevent my program from recognizing any account numbers. Without the i++, the program only recognizes the RBC002 account or John Baker's account.

Comment: Thats weird. Does it throw an exception when you run the program?